How to prevent duplicate nodes in return of Neo4j Cypher Query
I have this query to find missing links between nodes
MATCH (x:Birth)-[:SIBLING]-(y:Birth)-[:SIBLING]-(z:Birth)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:SIBLING]-(z)
RETURN x, collect([y, z]) AS openTriangles

Sometimes when I run it the same node can be in x one one row and z in a different row. Here is an example. Imagine the numbers are node IDs
x=123, openTraingles=\[\[456, 789\], \[456, 22\]\]
x=789, openTraingles=\[\[456, 123\]\]

If node 123 already appeared as x, it should not appear in openTriangles as it's a duplicate triangle. How could I amend the query to fix this?
I have tried but realised I can't use id() < id() as some nodes in openTriangle can have a lower id than x, as can be seen with node 123 and 22.

Can you show the data that returns those results? From your description, adding a condition of id(x) < id(z) should work to eliminate the duplicates that result from using undirected relationship patterns.

You should return each y and a collection of its distinct sorted x/z pairs:
MATCH (x:Birth)-[:SIBLING]-(y:Birth)-[:SIBLING]-(z:Birth)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:SIBLING]-(z)
RETURN y, COLLECT(DISTINCT apoc.coll.sort([x, z])) AS openTriangles

